Alternatives for creating DTMs with LM-Editor from VertiGIS
I currently only know the option of creating official digital terrain maps with the VertiGIS LM editor. (=digital representations of geographical features with detailed information about terrain, elevation, and landforms)
Are there other ways or software that can also create digital terrain maps on various scales?
Would it work with QGIS, for example? I have some doubts about that. The data processing is great, but not the performance with very large amounts of data, as would be the case there.

To create DTM and DEMs I use lidR
